# PIC16F887 receiving wrong UART Data

Tags: c, pic, uart

I'm making a cleaning robot in C (XC8) and I've got some problems with UART. Let me explain:

The project got an UART communication between a PIC16F887 and a HC06. Before, the project has a PIC16F1455 and worked great. But I needed more and changed the micro.
With an App based on Android (which I never change and I know it works fine) I send a char via Bluetooth to the HC06. Through UART, the HC06 send the char to the pic, and I change a variable named "Pressed" according to the data.

So... I configured everything, changed the registers for the new pic, put a LED to know if I'm receiving something in every receive interruption (which I do) but the variable never change (I guess I'm receiving trash data), and I'm using a simple "Data == Data" function to change the variable. My guess: the problem is the BAUD RATE. HC06 needs 9600, and somehow mine is different.

BAUD RATE needs the pic frequency and some register changes, right?

**I need to find why my BAUD RATE isn't 9600, can you help me?**

Here go some of my code, starting with the configuration bits. I'm going to use an internal oscillator and 8MHz:

```
 PIC16F887 Configuration Bit Settings

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTRC_NOCLKOUT // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSCIO oscillator: I/O function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled and can be enabled by SWDTEN bit of the WDTCON register)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // RE3/MCLR pin function select bit (RE3/MCLR pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown Out Reset Selection bits (BOR disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal External Switchover bit (Internal/External Switchover mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enabled bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF         // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit

// CONFIG2
#pragma config BOR4V = BOR21V   // Brown-out Reset Selection bit (Brown-out Reset set to 2.1V)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Self Write Enable bits (Write protection off)
```

Here goes the main function.

```
void main(void){
    
    GeneralConfig(); //Configuración general.
    BrushStart = 1; //Activamos el cepillo.
    TRISBbits.TRISB0 = 0; //TEST LED
    RB0 = 0; //TEST LED
    
    while(1){
    
        //THIS IS ANOTHER TEST
        if(Pressed==1){RB0 = 1;}
        else if(Pressed==2){RB0 = 0;}
        
    } //Bucle infinito.
     
    return;
}
```

The important here is: when Pressed is 1, the LED turns on and when it is 0 it turns off. Now, I'm gonna change OSCCON, according to the datasheet, for 8MHz internal oscillator.

```
//Oscilador
OSCCON = 0b01110101; //Internal 8MHz
```

Now, with my frequency, I'm configuring the USART:

```
void USARTConfig(void){ //USART Configuration

    //BAUDRATE (9600) = Fosc/(64*(SPBRG+1))
    
    BAUDCTL = 0b00000000;
    BRGH = 0;
    SPBRG = 12; 
    TXSTA = 0b10100110;
    RCSTA = 0b10010110; 

}
```

This should give me 9600 BAUD RATE. There is even a table (Table 12-5) in section 12.3 of the datasheet: with 8MHz, BRGH=0, BRG16=0, SPBRG=12 --> BAUD=9600.

Just in case, here is my reception code:

```
int USARTRead(char *Rxdata){

    int j=0;
    
    while(PIR1bits.RCIF){
         
            if(RCSTAbits.OERR == 1) //Overrun error           
               {RCSTAbits.CREN = 0; //Clear overrun error (disable receiver)                              
                RCSTAbits.CREN = 1;} //Enable receiver       
            if(RCSTAbits.FERR == 1) //Framing error bit
               {RCSTAbits.SPEN = 0; //Serial Port Disable
                RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1;}
                       
            Rxdata[j]=RCREG; 
            j++;
   
        }
    
    return j;

}
```

Here is what I do with the received data:

```
void ReceiveControl(char *Rxdata){

    if(DataCompare(Rxdata, "M",1)){
        ManualMode = 1;
        //BrushStart = 0;
        //Stop();
    }
    else if(DataCompare(Rxdata, "A",1)){       
        ManualMode = 0;
    }

    else if(DataCompare(Rxdata, "U",1)){Pressed = 1;} //Forward
    else if(DataCompare(Rxdata, "D",1)){Pressed = 2;} //Backward
    else if(DataCompare(Rxdata, "L",1)){Pressed = 3;} //Left
    else if(DataCompare(Rxdata, "R",1)){Pressed = 4;} //Right
    else if(DataCompare(Rxdata, "S",1)){Pressed = 0;} //Stop
    else if(DataCompare(Rxdata, "B",1)){BrushStart = 1;} //Brush Start
    else if(DataCompare(Rxdata, "X",1)){BrushStart = 0;} //Brush Stop
    

}
```

And last, how I compare the data received:

```
int DataCompare(unsigned char Buffer[], unsigned char Data[], unsigned int length){

    int i = 0;
    
    while(i<length){
        if(Buffer[i] == Data[i]){
        
            i++;
            if(i==length){
            
                return 1;
            }   
        }
        if(Buffer[i] != Data[i]){
        
            i=length;
            return 0;
        }           
    }
}
```

This exact functions where in my last project with the PIC16F1455, and they worked. I only changes registers because this is another pic. And they don't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong but I think you made a mistake setting BRGH.

According to the [datasheets](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001291H.pdf) I have:

[image: EUSART settings]

So if you set `BRGH = 0` but then do `TXSTA = 0b10100110` you are rewriting BRGH (bit 2) to 1, meaning you need to divide by 16 to calculate the baudrate.

If you load 12 onto SPBRG (`n` in the equation) you are probably running at 38.4k instead of 9.6kbaud.

When debugging UARTS I find absolutely necessary to have a scope close at hand to look at the signals.

The first sentence of your question won you an upvote.

Comment: You are right. I was setting BRGH again in TXSTA and I wasn't seeing it. I might get lost between the bits. Now everything works fine. My gratitude.

Comment: yeah, that happens... but it's what we are here for. Good luck with your robot.

Answer (score 1):

Try 16 MHz, Use a external oscillator. If you use a external oscillator it can go up to 20 MHz. If you don't have a external oscillator use 4 MHz and don't forget to change the SPBRG to 25 or 0X25.

And also change the asynonos and sychronus accordingly.

```
ANSEL=0X00;
ANSELH=0X00;

TXSTA=0X24;
RCSTA=0X90;
SPBRG=0X25;
```